# Need to know if a DDR4 SIMM is compatible with my computer

Tags: memory

My PC has a clock speed of 2133 MHz. Can it work with a 2666 MHz memory module?
I have 2 DIMM slots. Are they compatible with UDIMM memory modules?

My processor is an Intel Core i5-6600 3.3GHz.
BaseBoard Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
BaseBoard Product: H110M-A/M.2
BaseBoard Version: Rev X.0x
BIOS: 19/09/2016 / UEFI
SMBIOS Version: 3.0

Reference:
https://uk.crucial.com/gbr/en/ct2k32g4dfd8266

Comment: This needs more information: which motherboard are you using, and which CPU.

Comment: @MechEng - I added the processor. Is it possible to find out which motherboard I have without opening the case?

Comment: I got it: "System Information"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory you linked to will not work with your hardware.

But the issue here is not the maximum memory frequency of 2666 MT/s. Pretty much all DDR4 memory has an SPD profile for DDR4-2133, because that is the common baseline for DDR4. If you put compatible DDR4-2666 into your system, it will be clocked at DDR4-2133.
The problem here is capacity: While your CPU could support a total of 64GB of RAM, your mainboard only supports up to 32GB of RAM total: https://www.asus.com/de/Motherboards/H110M-A-M-2/specifications/
So the maximum amount of system memory you can use is 2x16GB, and not the 2x32GB you linked.

Edit: also, UDIMM is the only type of memory you can use in your system. RDIMM and LRDIMM are not supported.

Comment: This answer has some good info, but the statement that the memory is not compatible may not be correct. This motherboard was released in 2016, and the first 32GB DDR4 modules became available in 2018. The reason the specs say that 32GB is the maximum is due to the fact that ASUS couldn't qualify any 32 GB modules when they released this board; It is *very* likely that they will work anyways because it is the CPU itself that would determine any hard capacity limit. Consider that the linked memory is probably *compatible*, but is not *qualified*.

Comment: That's a good point, but still, you would need to try this at your own risk. For example, I still haven't seen anyone use 32GB UDIMMs successfully on X99 platforms.

Comment: [i7-6950X](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/94456/intel-core-i7-6950x-processor-extreme-edition-25m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz.html), [i5-6600](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88188/intel-core-i5-6600-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html) -- It looks like both of these CPUs specify a max memory capacity that is exactly 16GB x the number of slots their boards can have. So maybe you're right that these 32GB modules won't work with the i5-6600...